# Rails date select options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, date, internationalization

I have a date_select field in my rails application as follows:

```
<%= f.date_select :dateinstructed %>
```

I would like to re-order the drop down lists show they output as:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
```

According to what I have read you can use the :order option, but I am unsure how to actually use this option:

```
<%= f.date_select :dateinstructed, :order = {:day, :month, :year} %>
```

Obviously this isn't right, but what am I supposed to put in place of the:

```
:day, :month, :year
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
<%= f.date_select :dateinstructed, :order => [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Reffer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001698

Comment: Thanks, the reason I couldn't get it working was this line of the API link you showed me:

date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})

I was using options = {} not options = []

Comment: Well, not really... You were using `options = {}` but it was hidden from you. The form helper functions in rails will assume all the parameters passed after the required parameters to be a hash unless both the options and html_options are implicitly passed in. So in your case, after rails does it's parameter fun tricks, you are passing this `f.date_select :dateinstructed, { :order => [:day, :month, :year] }, {}`. That is why, when you want html options you have to close the options in curly braces ({}).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
  prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }
```